# Error when Parsing XML file with Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

The below posted function, is to parse a XML file and to display the tag name "employee".
But when I load the .HTML file -which includes the below posted function- in the web browser (Chrome), the function does not display the contents of the variable "x", I do not know what is the mistake in that code.

Please give me an example of, how to, display the contents of the XML file.

**html file**:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">   
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="readXML.css" type="text/css">
     <title>Read First Child</title>

        <!-- <xml ID="Schriftsteller" SRC="D:\files\files\Schriftsteller.xml"></xml> -->

           <script language="JavaScript">

           var dname = "D:\files\files\xml.xml";
              function findWriter() 
              {
                 var xmlDoc;
                    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                    {
                      xmlDoc=new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                      xmlDoc.open("GET",dname,false);
                      xmlDoc.send("");
                         return xmlDoc.responseXML;
                    } 
                 // IE 5 and IE 6
                    else if (ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM"))
                    {
                      xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                      xmlDoc.async=false;
                      xmlDoc.load(dname);
                         return xmlDoc;
                    }
                         alert("Error loading document!");
                        return null;

                 var  x, xmlDOC;

                 xmlDoc = loadXMLDoc("D:\files\files\xml.xml");
                 x = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("employee");
                 document.Write(x);
              }
           </script>
    </head>
   <body onload="loadXMLDoc(dname)">
   <span ID="blueBack">Read firstChild</span>
   <div>
   <form name="show"
   <input type=text name="me">
   <input type="button" value="Display Writer"
   onClick="findWriter()">
   </form>
  </div>
```

**xml.xml**

```
< ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<company>
    <employee id="001" >John</employee>
    <turnover>
        <year id="2000">100,000</year>
        <year id="2001">140,000</year>
        <year id="2002">200,000</year>
    </turnover>
</company>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is where you're trying to get the employee info from the XML.  You should change your line where you set x as follows:

```
x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("employee");
```

**UPDATE:**

My apologies - I should have looked deeper into your code.  I found numerous issues / errors, but, luckily, I recently had to do some XML parsing, so I have the basics of what you want below:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
      <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">   
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="readXML.css" type="text/css">
      <title>Read First Child</title>

      <!-- <xml ID="Schriftsteller" SRC="D:\files\files\Schriftsteller.xml"></xml> -->

      <script language="JavaScript">

         var dname = "D:\files\files\xml.xml";
         var xmlDoc;
         if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
         xmlDoc = new XMLHttpRequest();
         } else {
         // IE 5/6
         xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
         }
         function findWriter() {
            xmlDoc.open("GET",dname,false);
            xmlDoc.send();
            var xmlResponse = xmlDoc.responseXML;
            var first = xmlResponse.getElementsByTagName("employee")[0];
            var name, id;
            if(typeof(first.textContent) != 'undefined')
               name = first.textContent;
            else if(typeof(first.text) != 'undefined')
               name = first.text; // IE
            id = first.getAttribute('id');
            //console.log('Employee '+name+', ID '+id);
            document.write('Employee '+name+', ID '+id+'<br>');
            var years = xmlResponse.getElementsByTagName("year");
            var year, sales;
            for(var i=0; i<years.length; i++) {
               year = years[i].getAttribute('id');
               if(typeof(years[i].textContent) != 'undefined')
                  sales = years[i].textContent;
               else if(typeof(years[i].text) != 'undefined')
                  sales = years[i].text; // IE
               //console.log('year '+year+' sales='+sales);
               document.write('year '+year+' sales='+sales+'<br>');
            }
            document.close();
         }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <span ID="blueBack">Read firstChild</span>
      <div>
         <form name="show">
            <input type=text name="me">
            <input type="button" value="Display Writer"
               onClick="findWriter()">
         </form>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

**Almost forgot:**

Your XML sample has a minor error; change the first line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

Comment: @Amr Bakri - I hope my updated answer helps.  XML is not very simple to handle in javascript.  If you are able to control the data input format, consider using JSON.  :)

Answer (score -1):

I do not see many callbacks. So my guess is making the your code more async can help... But here is a tutorial how to do something like this with jQuery (famous Javascript library which helps alot)

http://think2loud.com/224-reading-xml-with-jquery/

Comment: why the down vote? it is the proper way to access and parse file via webrequest on a server and not access the file system from within a webpage. var dname = "D:\files\files\xml.xml"; <- not good!